# Create node from another node

Tags: 8, nodes, entities

How do I create a node from an existing content type on front end? Let's say we have a article i need to associate tags with it in a fashion.
For example a book of tags which a user can view . Either we can create a book or we can add tags to an already existing book. Those books are binded to a user also.

Comment: Explain little more in your question. It's unclear what you are saying and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @AAjayReddy I need to save articles just like in pin interest we can create a book with the pins. So that the user can go to an article and save that article into an existing book or he can create it on the go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if what I getting from you is right then you have to look into Taxonomy Vocabulary and terms.

So you can have a Vocabulary of Sports but under sports there are so many taxonomy terms - types of sports, like footbal,hockey,basketball etc

then for your content type you add a taxonomy field mapped to the sports vocabulary

now users can create content and add the various tags/terms to it.

if not then you may have to look at using books in drupal

Comment: I agree with everything you say but i dont want the user to go to the backend to add references to football,hockey,etc for a content type of book. I want the user to do it under the article just like we do with comments but a little different.

Comment: Yes I get you, the user doent have to access backend for that. when the user logs in he, he can add content of that content type - books, but there will be a tag field now showing either as select list, autocomplete, or checkboxes. and if they should be able to add their own refrences like skating if when not in the list, then use the autocomplete widget, so they just type their new term and it gets added to the rest. so there will be no need for them to access backend.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a ready-to-use answer, but hopefully a nod in the right direction...

Have a look at the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module. In Drupal 7, you could build something like that with Flag and the [Flag Lists](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_lists) modules. For Drupal 8 I'm not sure, but I guess it's worth giving it a try.

Comment: Thank you , thats what i was looking for. I dont mind coding a little as long as its not from scratch

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! Maybe you can even contribute some of your code back to the community, for instance if you succeed to port Flag Lists to Drupal 8. There's already an [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_lists/issues/2680193) for that, perhaps there's some code written too.